# Unable to connect remote Hadoop cluster using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

I'm running a reconciliation application using Spark. This application needs to connect a Hbase table from 2 different clusters and compare the data. My application is able to connect and get the data from where the application is running on a cluster.

but for remote cluster I'm getting below error

f`ailed on local exception:exception is Failed after attempts=4, exceptions: 2023-04-19T17:11:13.491Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1681924273451, pause=1000, maxAttempts=4}, java.io.IOException: Call to Host:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found no valid authentication method from options 2023-04-19T17:11:14.505Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1681924273451, pause=1000, maxAttempts=4}, java.io.IOException: Call to host:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found no valid authentication method from options 2023-04-19T17:11:16.522Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1681924273451, pause=1000, maxAttempts=4}, java.io.IOException: Call to host:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found no valid authentication method from options 2023-04-19T17:11:19.549Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1681924273451, pause=1000, maxAttempts=4}, java.io.IOException: Call to host:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found no valid authentication method from options`

Is anyone know how to fix this issue? I have also set  `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(userLoginString, keytabPath);` with username and keytab file path